# mmenu plugin check if sliding is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mmenu

I have some CSS that adds a div across the whole page.

I have this css applied to a div:
`.full-width {`
  `position: relative;`
  `margin: 0 -9999rem;`
  `padding: .25rem 9999rem;`
  `background: #e92428;`
  `color: white;`
  `font-size: 1.125rem;`
  `height:100px;`
`}`

When I click the menu button of the mmenu plugin, the div is still across and on top of the menu.
To solve this, I removed the css from the div that makes it go across the entire screen when the user clicks on the menu icon.
My issue now is applying the css back to the div when the user clicks on the main page to slide it back in place.
Where can I check if the user clicked the main page so I can re-add the css to my div?

Comment: You need to provide some code, it's very difficult to understand what you are trying to accomplish and in what context.

Answer (score 0):

Mmenu triggers events when clicked: `opening`, `opened`, `closing`, `closed`. It looks like you want to tie into the `opened` function with your CSS. Here is how to trigger each of those functions:

```
jQuery('#mmenu').data('mmenu').bind('opening', function(){
    //When mmenu has started opening
}).bind('opened', function(){
    //After mmenu has finished opening
}).bind('closing', function(){
    //When mmenu has started closing
}).bind('closed', function(){
    //After mmenu has finished closing
});
```

Obviously, change the `#menu` jQuery selector to match yours.

That being said, if you're struggling with z-index, you might want to look into the `zposition` of the mmenu init `offCanvas` options so that it stays in front (since the default is `back`):

```
jQuery('#mmenu').mmenu({
    offCanvas: {
        zposition: "front", //"back" (default), "front", "next"
        position: "left" //"left" (default), "right", "top", "bottom"
    }
});
```